# Is a function terminates as soon as it returns a value, ignoring its next lines?

Tags: c++

What value the `return_a_number` function returns in following case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int return_a_number(int n)
{
 if(n < 0) return -1;

 return 1;
}

int main()
{
 cout << "Enter any number: ";
 cin >> num;
 cout << return_a_number(num);
  
 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

As `return 1` is the last statement of function, Is it returns 1 everytime?

I'm new in c++. So I've many confusions.

Comment: when a function `return`s the following lines are not executed. Your question is not quite clear. You can run the code with a debugger attached to see what it does

Comment: *"Plz ignore the error(s)"* - That's an ineffective strategy when attempting to correct your code.  Since this code doesn't even compile then I guess the answer to your question is that the `print` function doesn't return anything and none of its lines of code are ever executed.

Comment: There are so many things wrong about this code, are you sure you want us to ignore them? Regarding your question, when the function returns, it terminates there, it doesn't execute the subsequent lines of code in that function (if any).

Comment: `j=int print(n);` should be `j = print(n);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function returns, it terminates there, following lines of code in that function will not be executed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string foo(int x)
{
    if(x < 0) return "If x < 0, this will be returned";
    if(x == 0) return "If x == 0, this will be returned";
    
    return "If x > 0, this will be returned";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo(-1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
If x < 0, this will be returned
If x == 0, this will be returned
If x > 0, this will be returned
```